error reading configuration file : parse error on line 1 server -1
After installing the program, I encountered this error. How to eliminate this error? When running the program, it gives this error thanks. (bitcoin core)

Please, if anyone knows how to solve my problem, I would be grateful

Please update your question to include the contents of your bitcoin.conf file. Without seeing that it's hard to guess what might be wrong.

I wanted to activate bitcoin mining, and then I went to the settings section, configured three codes, and clicked the save option. I thought it was not saved. At the bottom of the program, I clicked the save change option. After this, when I run the program again, I face this error.

I just downloaded the program, I had created a wallet, and then it took two or three hours. The program file had to be downloaded in order to activate the transaction and send bitcoins in my wallet.

You'll need to describe the actions you took in far more detail.

It sounds like the configuration changes that were made to your Bitcoin Core are incorrect. Try checking them for mistakes against the instructions you were following, or remove them to use the default configuration. If you want concrete help with the error, please share details on the configuration you are using (please obscure sensitive information like access credentials if any appears in the configuration).
